# Byte object comparing

Tags: java, byte

I have a method object.getType() returning Byte value. Later there is a check `object.getType() == 1`. This is literal comparing, so value should be checked, not reference. When this check may give false(in case values are equal)?

Comment: Is this an interview question or do you have a real-life use problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Post your actual code.